# mating emacs buffers to grouped windows in Windows

Tags: windows, emacs, buffer

I imagine this is too platform-specific and may need to be 'hacked on' to emacs rather than being a preexisting feature (if it even can be done)... but I'll ask anyway.

You know how Windows can aggregate all the windows associated with a given process (whether multiple instances of the process or multiple windows tied to the same process) into a single icon on the taskbar?

I'm wondering if I can have a single emacs process and a single window but multiple buffers open, and be able to see each buffer represented as a window when I hover over the emacs icon on the taskbar--when I click on the virtual window from the taskbar corresponding to a given buffer, it switches to that buffer in the process window and pops it?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I don't think this is possible, at least not out of the box.

Actually, what you see grouped under the same task-bar icon is the list of Emacs *frames*, not windows or buffers. MS Windows knows nothing about Emacs buffers or windows.  It knows Emacs frames as MS Windows windows.